# How to store private variables in Substrate storage

Tags: substrate

I want to store private variables in Substrate storage and I don't want to encode them. For example I have this structure and I want to store private variable in it.

```
pub struct TestStruct {
  // Some public variables

  // Could there be a private variable?
  test_private: u64, 
}
```

I understand that according to the idea in the blockchain, everything should be public, and that most likely the variable will need to be encrypted. I heard about the 'reveal pattern', does it help in this case?

Comment: Just for the record, Stack Overflow appears to have made that comment on my behalf when I reported this question as a duplicate of the one you linked @ShawnTabrizi

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to explain what is your usecase more precisely.

What does private variable means, who has access to it ?

As far as I know 'reveal pattern' is when you send the hash of what you will reveal, and then later you can reveal what was the original value, by checking the on-chain hash.